# Where do I insert commas when I have 'for which' and 'both...and' in one sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I need some advice on the punctuation in this sentence. Specifically around 'for which' and 'both...and'. When do I insert commas?

I hold both a Master of Literature for which I was awarded Pass A with distinction, and a Master of Communication.

Comment: *I hod Master's degrees both in Literature and in Communications, and for the former one I was awarded the Pass A with distinction.*

Comment: @mahmud koya You're also a bricklayer's mate?

Comment: The simplest answer without unnecessary changes would be 'I hold both a Master of Literature, for which I was awarded Pass A with distinction, and a Master of Communication.'

Answer (score 1):

The clause *for which I was awarded pass A with distinction* is not a *defining* clause, and so it's better to include some sort of punctuation. But you're right, the comma doesn't sit too happily with *both*. What about using brackets instead? *I hold both a Master of Literature (for which I was awarded Pass A with distinction) and a Master of Communication.*